# How to make requestbody controller works?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, database, spring

So actually everything is working well, except the fact that i can't get access to "inscrit" which is supposed to be the one which is sent to have the information user

This is my function in javascript and it does go into success for ajax.

```
function fbLogin() {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    var inscrit = {
                        "prenom": response.first_name,
                        "nom": response.last_name,
                        "email": response.email
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'post',
                        url: '/hello/facebookconnection',
                        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        data: JSON.stringify(inscrit),
                        datatype: "json",
                        success: function() {
                        window.alert('User data sent');}
                        ,
                        error: function(){
                            window.alert('Error in sending ajax data');}
                    });
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.';
                }
            }, {scope: 'email'});
        }
```

And this is my java controller (whatever i do, the "inscrit.getEmail()" is always null)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/facebookconnection", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody public void createUser(@RequestBody inscrit inscrit, ModelMap model) throws Exception {
    //System.out.println(inscrit.getNom());
    //System.out.println(inscrit.getPrenom());
    System.out.println(inscrit.getEmail());
    try {
        user.adduser(inscrit);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my inscrit class with all the getter and setter correctly set (i know that there's no problem with it)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="inscrit")
public class inscrit implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name="email")
  private String email;

  @Column(name="nom")
  private String nom;

  @Column(name="prenom")
  private String prenom;
}
```

So i would like to know if someone could help me understand why it's not working in my controller (how to do so the data is sent properly from the ajax to the controller) :(
Thx !

EDIT : i did write the answer of that question below. The problem was the fact that response.first_name was really blank... and had to pass through the function userdata() which had the real informations. So that means i don't have any real error in my code, all the informations between the controller and my jsp page works correctly. Be free to use it as an example of how this works

Comment: As a general tip, classes in Java should start with a capital letter. If you're using Spring, that might actually be part of the problem, I remember the annotations do weird things if you don't correctly use camelCase. Try changing it to `Inscrit`, couldn't hurt.

Comment: `(whatever i do, the "inscrit.getEmail()" is always null)`  have you checked if email is *actually* present in the response from FB.login?(`response.email`)

Comment: Hum.. i also thought of it, but in this project, my friend made it works with lower case for inscrit, he has no problem using this to create an account in the site and then to connect it. So the inscription and connection works properly. But since this one is for a connection via facebook, i have to go via ajax which he didn't.

Comment: yes i did, the email is shown correctly for response.email

Comment: So my situation is more like i know that all the informations are correct, but i don't know why "@RequestBody inscrit inscrit" is not working. i might miss something stupid, but after watching for hours in internet, i don't see any error.... :(

Comment: Fair enough. I don't see anything obviously wrong. If you are using Spring(this looks like it), you should add that as a tag to your question so people more familiar with it can help.

Comment: okay :( thx anyway (i did add Spring like you asked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer to my own question since i found the answer, So this is for people who tries to have a facebook api and want to get informations of the profil to put into database.
My error was the fact that i thought response in login was the same asthe UserData(), which is not the case... So that's how i was supposed to do it.

```
        function fbLogin() {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    // Get and display the user profile data
                    getFbUserData();
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.';
                }
            }, {scope: 'email'});
        }

        // Fetch the user profile data from facebook
        function getFbUserData(){
            FB.api('/me', {locale: 'en_US', fields: 'id,first_name,last_name,email,link,gender,locale,picture'},
                function (response) {
                    /*document.getElementById('fbLink').setAttribute("onclick","fbLogout()");
                    document.getElementById('fbLink').innerHTML = 'Logout from Facebook';
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.first_name + '!';
                    document.getElementById('userData').innerHTML = '<div class="fbprofile"><p><b>FB ID:</b> '+response.id+'</p><p><b>Name:</b> '+response.first_name+' '+response.last_name+'</p><p><b>Email:</b> '+response.email+'</p><p><b>Gender:</b> '+response.gender+'</p><p><b>Locale:</b> '+response.locale+'</p></div><p><b>Picture:</b> <img src="'+response.picture.data.url+'"/></p>';*/
                    var inscrit = {
                        "prenom": response.first_name,
                        "nom": response.last_name,
                        "password": "1234",
                        "status": 0,
                        "email": response.email
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'post',
                        url: '/hello/facebookconnection',
                        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        data: JSON.stringify(inscrit),
                        datatype: "json",
                        success: function() {
                            document.location.href = "accueilmember";
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            window.alert('Error in sending ajax data');}
                    });
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my controller class.This just logs the post request send to the server:(You may modify this if you need something more like adding a Response Body)

```
@RestController
public class EmailController {      
    @RequestMapping(value = "/facebookconnection", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public void createUser(@RequestBody inscrit inscrit) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(inscrit.getNom());
        System.out.println(inscrit.getPrenom());
        System.out.println(inscrit.getEmail());



    }
```

This is my **inscrit.java** class(I  personally think naming the class would not affect but better follow standard naming Practices like **Inscrit.java**)

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class inscrit implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8445943548965154778L;

       private String email;

       private String prenom;

       private String nom;

       public inscrit() {
            super();
        }

        public inscrit(String email,String prenom,String nom) {
            this.setEmail(email);
            this.setPrenom(prenom);
            this.setNom(nom);

        }
       public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }


    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }


    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }


    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }


    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }


    }
```

I did a post request from Advanced Rest Client and set the payload as

```
{
 "email":"agdfae@gmail.com",
 "prenom":"qewrwe",
 "nom":"qwer"

}
```

the results were

```
qwer
qewrwe
agdfae@gmail.com
```

You can modify this to suit your own needs.Hope this helps

**EDIT:**

You will need more two classes in spring boot as below:

**ServletInitializer.java**

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(PostDataApplication.class);
    }

}
```

**PostDataApplication .java**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class PostDataApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PostDataApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

PostDataApplication is the name of the application.

These four classes will do the trick (with pom.xml only no other xml configuration needed since this is springboot).Let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: Well then it means that the only difference is in the controller, i tried what you have but it's still not working... is there like a version needed for this? like for the mvc-dispatcher-servlet or web.xml or hibernate.cfg.xml?

Answer (score 0):

```
@ResponseBody public void createUser(@RequestParam(value="inscrit") String inscrit) throws Exception {
//System.out.println(inscrit.getNom());
//System.out.println(inscrit.getPrenom());

Inscrit ins = JSON.parseObject(inscrit, Inscrit.class);
System.out.println(ins.getEmail());    
try {
    user.adduser(ins);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}  }
```

The class of **inscrit.java** is nonstandard.You should change it to **Inscrit**.**java**.

I hope this helps.

Comment: JSON.parseObject is not recognize xD what should i do?

Comment: download jar file.    http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.alibaba/fastjson/1.2.5